# Finding the day x years,months from a given time (Python)

Tags: python, date, math

Have a maths question here which I know to solve using only pen and paper. Takes a while with that approach, mind you. Does anybody know to do this using Python? I've done similar questions involving "dates" but none involving "days". Any of you folk able to figure this one out?

The date on 25/11/1998 is a Wednesday. What is the day on 29/08/2030?

Can anyone at least suggest an algorithm?

Cheers

Comment: Please don't use both [python-2.7] and [python-3.x] tags. If the version is irrelevant, use neither.

Comment: Do you actually need an algorithm to do this yourself (for a class, because you need dates outside the limit of `str[pf]time`, whatever…)? Or is Haidro's answer all you need?

Answer (score 2):

Use the wonderful [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime('29/08/2030', '%d/%M/%Y')
>>> print mydate.strftime('%A')
Tuesday
```

Comment: That's kind of cheating. :)

Comment: @Wooble Welcome to Python

Comment: This doesn't actually say how to get the date X years, Y months from a given time. For that, you might need an extra line of code! :)

Comment: @abarnert Oh yea. We'll wait for the OP I guess

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm/math is quite simple: There are always 7 days a week. Just calculate how many days between the two days, add it to the weekday of the given day then mod the sum by 7.

```
<!-- language: python -->
> from datetime import datetime
> given_day = datetime(1998,11,25)
> cal_day = datetime(2030,8,29)
> print cal_day.weekday()
 3
> print (given_day.weekday() + (cal_day-given_day).days) % 7
 3
```